# Sell free product with existing simple product

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

I'm integrating our magento 1.9.3.4 store with our inventory management system(cin7) and I'm trying to figure out how best to setup free products that sell automatically with existing simple products during regularly changing promotions.

About once a month 30+ products will offer a bonus product at no cost.

I could create a bundle product in magento or the inventory system but it would take a lot of time to manage them as I'd have to:

> - create bundle product
> - disable original product
> - change bundle products sku/url to be the same as the original product so it continues to work with feeds/seo/etc.
> - change all this back once the promotion is over

Ideally I'd attach the bonus product to an existing parent product at no cost and it wouldn't be seen anywhere but in the backend order view or the checkout/cart as a product line.

If anyone can suggest a good way to manage this I'd appreciate it, I'm hoping there is an extension that does this that I haven't been able to find. Or maybe there is a cleaner solution I haven't even considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with core Magento functionality. We use Aheadworks Add Free Product To Cart extension. It seems to do everything you want https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/add-free-product-to-cart.html

Comment: oh interesting I hadn't come across that. Can it automatically add the "free" product to the cart at the same time as adding the parent product? without interrupting the customer with a popup or asking for confirmation?

Comment: It's configurable (per rule setting) to show a pop-up/confirmation or just add straight into the the cart. It uses the same mechanisms as promotion rules.

Comment: Word of caution though - I'm not sure if you can have the free product visibility set to 'Not visible individually'. All the products we give free can be bought in their own right and have visibility set to 'catalog/search'. If you want I can do a quick test on our dev site?

Comment: Thanks mate I hadn't thought of that! I've set it up and I'll do the testing, but your offer is very kind. Thanks for submitting your answer it's really saved me from a headache